# CRM Workflow Process doesn't trigger on record created through Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, process, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM, I have a workflow process when a record is created.

When I create a new record using Entity Framework(EF), the workflow is not triggered. But it triggers fine when I create a record using Organization Service Proxy.

Below is my code to create a new record using EF.

```
Entity e = db.Entity.Create();
//
......
//
e.Entity.Add(e);
e.SaveChanges();
```

Above code works fine and it creates a new record. But it doesn't trigger the Workflow Process.

What could be the solution in this scenario?

Comment: What version of Dynamics are you using? And is it on-premise or online? How are you connecting Entity Framework to Dynamics?

Comment: You are accessing Dynamics DB directly, bypassing its engine for workflows and plugins. You need to use SDK. It's highly not recommended to do any business related operations directly on CRM database.

Comment: @KonstantinErshov - this should be an answer, not a comment :)